# Redirecting inside a phonegap application is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm attempting to redirect to a locally stored html file inside of my application but it just refreshes the page... I've tried a few different approach with all the same results. However, document.location.reload works.

Here are a few lines that I've already tried (url being the path to the local html file, I've tried the full url with the file:/// protocol and relative path)

```
document.location.href = url;
document.location = url;
window.location.href = url;
window.location = url;
window.open(url, "_self");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up with the following solution :

```
var link = $("<a href='" + url + "'></a>");
$("body").append(link);
link.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure these are solutions, but just some things to check for.

Ensure that you're not inadvertently redirecting to yourself (same page).

Ensure that you're not stuck in a loop because you're redirecting to a page that automatically redirects back to the original page.

If you're using jQuery Mobile, try using the page container's Change() method instead.

Comment: I am not redirecting to myself, and I am not using jQuery Mobile.
To be sure about the redirection, I have alerts that are shown on the page load and I am monitoring the page via weinre.